# 2 versions of pg_dump on my OSX Lion

Tags: macos, postgresql, osx-lion, version, pg-dump

I had Postgres 9.0.x installed with homebrew, but because of lack of some modules I removed it using:

```
brew uninstall postgres
```

and installed Postgres 9.1.3 from  http://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads.

Now I've got a problem - 2 different versions on pg_dump - 9.0.5 and 9.1.3 and 9.0.5 is the default version.

Is there any way to set the 9.1.3 version as the default version of pg_dump?

Comment: i found an old version here /usr/bin

Comment: Delete the old version, or rename it, or move it to a directory that it is not in the PATH.

Comment: Why can't you just remove the old binary of pg_dump?

Comment: i did - i moved pg_dump to my home directory (just in case) but now when i type: pg_dump --version in the Terminal i've got: -bash: pg_dump: command not found

Comment: This means your new version of pg_dump is not in your PATH.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

So based on your additional comments, your new version of pg_dump is not in your PATH, all you need to do is to remove the old version, and symlink the new one to any directory in your PATH, for example, **/usr/bin**.

Like follows:

```
sudo ln -s /actual/new/pg_dump /usr/bin/pg_dump
```

Hope this helps

Comment: here is what I did with Homebrew as the upgrade didn't fully work for me. Just change the version number with your postgresql version that Homebrew installed: http://blog.swathik.com/2013/06/pgdump-version-mismatch.html

Comment: sudo ln -s /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.5/bin/pg_dump /usr/bin/pg_dump
ln: /usr/bin/pg_dump: Operation not permitted

Answer (score 8):

Valentin has the right answer, but of course, the question for Mac users is where the heck is pg_dump?

If you have version 9.2, it's: /Library/PostgreSQL/9.2/bin/pg_dump

Just copy this to /usr/bin

Comment: if you used homebrew, it's /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.2/bin (or whatever your version is)

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same error essentially.

`pg_dump: server version: 9.1.3; pg_dump version: 9.0.4`

I just used homebrew's upgrade feature, and it brought both the sever and pg_dump versions up to date with the latest version in homebrew (9.3 as of 9/19/13).

`brew upgrade postgresql`

I reran my dump statement, and it worked perfectly.

`pg_dump -U postgres development > dump.sql`